# form POST submission on playframework is too slow

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

In my play 2.0 application developed with scala 2.9.1 , when I submit a form with POST 
it is too slow and sometimes the page is not displayed.However for GET method its working fine.

My routes config

```
POST    /login                      controllers.Application.login
```

when called from html

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
```

the page is not displayed.

Please suggest what I'm missing

Comment: Any errors on console. Can you post the code of the login method?

Comment: I hit a similar issue, duplicate your routes "GET /assets/.../*files" line for POST -- if you look in firebug or similar browser inspector, a good chance you'll be getting timeouts on assets, not the page itself

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as virtualeyes, have a look at it using firebug or with chrome press F12 and choose network...